# Calculate subnet CIDR range

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-vpc

I am designing some private subnets within my VPC and will be using 3 subnets in 3 availability zones. My VPC is setup to use `10.0.0.0/16`, and I was to setup each of my subnets to use `/20` which will give me 4096 possible ip's per subnet.

So if I set my cidr of the first subnet to `10.0.0.0/20` which ip would be the next available ip to use for my second subnet?

I usually use `/24` for subnet cidr ranges so if I do the math properly if I use `/20` the next available ip I can use for the second subnet would be `10.0.16.0/20` and the third subnet can use `10.0.32.0/20`.

Is that correct?

Comment: Lots of calculators out there, for example: https://www.site24x7.com/tools/ipv4-subnetcalculator.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an online [CIDR Calculator](http://www.subnet-calculator.com/cidr.php)

Once you enter your CIDR, it will show you the address range.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the helpful tool :)